# Fontawesome is not working as the icons are not showing in the page

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have added the fontawesome link from their website but the icons are not showing in the page

I have used two links i.e

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5a384e9641.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>
```

for `<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-pancakes"></i>`

but not working

Comment: You are using version `4.3.0`, which still needs the `fa` class added to the icon element to properly work in the first place; and second, v4.3 does not appear to contain the icons you want to use. `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` for example would work fine with the version you are using.

Answer (score -1):

> You are using version `4.3.0`, which still needs the `fa` class added
> to the icon element to properly work in the first place; and second,
> v4.3 does not appear to contain the icons you want to use. `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` for example, would work fine with the
> version you are using.

*(moved [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76054391/fontawesome-is-not-working-as-the-icons-are-not-showing-in-the-page/77665884#comment134132037_76054391) to answer for easier solution finding, credit @CBroe)*